# Location and distance calculation using Wifi in android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, wifi, distance

How to get the distance of our mobile device from a wifi hotspot kept inside a building? This is basically for navigational purposes inside the building.. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use WiFi for indoor location (step 1 before navigation), then distance to the WiFi Access Points is not the correct approach. Instead use [RSSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication).

With Android you would need to take  WiFi fingerprint of a building by moving around every few meters and [sample the RSSI strength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#calculateSignalLevel%28int,%20int%29).  You need to provide a user interface that lets the user manually specify on an image of the building (e.g. a CAD drawing). Doing this will build up a database of what the RSSI is for different locations in the building. When you come to use this data for locating a user indoors, then you need an app to take the RSSI strength measurement and compare it against the database you've prepared to find the appropriate match.

Notes:
- If anyone adds/removes access points, you'll need to resample the building
- The measurements can be affected by density of people
- Some access points are variable strength access points, so the RSSI fingerprint is not consistent.
- This won't work with iPhone because there is no API to get the RSSI strength.

So, it is a useful, but not perfect way to get indoor location. There are a lot of more detailed articles on RSSI fingerprinting available.

Of course, navigation has to be built on to of that then.

Answer (score 1):

Hi [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543393/kris)

I understood what you are asking, The distance between Wifi access point and the Receiver, correct ? If yes, then it seem to be not possible after watching the discussion below.

[Click here to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684781/how-to-get-distance-using-wi-fi)