# Localization through multiple WiFi spots in building

Tags: java, android, wifi

Does any one know if it is possible to implement mobile application for android, which main purpose is to provide exact location of phone in a building. I have multiple WiFi hotspots with the same SSID. How precise would it be (if possible)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these, they could be helpful:

[how to get distance using Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684781/how-to-get-distance-using-wi-fi)

[Location and distance calculation using Wifi in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921157/location-and-distance-calculation-using-wifi-in-android)

if not, try to give more info. But using this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication should do.